# Setting up ecommerce tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I am setting up ecommerce tracking for a client and have a few questions to aid my understanding of Google Analytics.

I understand that you have to have an '_addItem' for every product that appears in the receipt.  Does this require a change of the JavaScript in any way, or does it use what is already there to generate each item's data automatically?

My other question is: when the JavaScript pulls the transaction and item information from the receipt, do I have to do anything to my website code to make sure that the identifiers used in the JavaScript match the identifiers within the receipt?  How does the JavaScript below know what 'total' means in terms of the data it is collecting?

I hope I have made myself clear, please ask if you would like me to elaborate. I'm really just trying to get my head around how this works and what I need to do to get it working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pageTracker._addTrans(
"order-id", // required
"affiliate or store name",
"total",
  "tax",
  "shipping",
  "city",
  "state",
  "country"
);

pageTracker._addItem(
  "order-id", // required
  "SKU",
  "product name",
  "product category",
  "unit price",  // required
  "quantity"  //required
);

pageTracker._trackTrans();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics will not autopopulate the reports based on the current page. GA doesn't parse anything on the page. You need to pass all information manually as the parameters to `_addTrans` and `_addItem`.

The documentation is very detailed and explains how you should implement it. But in the end the code snippets are just examples. you should generate the code snippets yourself dinamically based on server side logic in order to populate the code with the correct info for that transaction.

[Official guide to implement Ecommerce Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce)

Comment: Thanks, Eduardo.

I have read this guide but I'm still left with questions.  This guide seems to detail what needs to happen but not so much how to link up the transaction data with the Google Analytics code.

When the page sees "pageTracker._addItem( "order-id" ... ", is 'order-id' a specific identifier that is looking for an 'order-id' identifier in the pages code?  I'm sorry if this is easy stuff for you, but it's stressing me out!

Comment: It doesn't look for anything on the page. You have to pass all data regarding the transaction using the parameters to _addItem and _addTrans. Most of them are just arbitrary strings.